# JS files compiled by TypeScript not included when publishing though they are included when building in Debug and Release mode

Tags: .net, typescript, msbuild, maui, publish

I have a .NET MAUI project with TypeScript in `Scripts\scriptfiles.ts` folder that is compiled into `wwwroot\js\scriptfiles.js`. Everything works well until my client tries to publish it and everything stops working and I realized all script files are missing. I noticed that building with both `Debug` and `Release` build works but as soon as I use `publish`, the files are missing, both in the `\obj\Release\net8.0-android\assets\wwwroot\js` folder and the APK file (I can open and check it with 7zip).

This is the publishing command:

```
dotnet "publish" "-f:net8.0-android" "-c:Release" "/p:AndroidKeyStore=True" "/p:AndroidSigningKeyStore=<keyfile>" "/p:AndroidSigningStorePass=<pass>" "/p:AndroidSigningKeyAlias=<key>" "/p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=<keypass>" "D:\Github\MauiWithTypeScriptBug\MauiWithTypeScriptBug\MauiWithTypeScriptBug.csproj"
```

The TypeScript files is compiled using `Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild`:

```xml
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" Version="5.2.2">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
```

It happens to newly create projects as well. You can checkout this [Github repository](https://github.com/datvm/MauiWithTypeScriptBug) and reproduce it.

What's the problem here and why is it happening even though it works for Release build?

---

This is the `tsconfig.json` file even though I don't think it's relevant because the build works well in Debug or Release mode:

```json
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "ESNext",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "outDir": "wwwroot/js"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "wwwroot"
    ]
}
```

Comment: You're using the nuget as a design-time dependency, so it won't work for publishing. If you reference it as a runtime dependency (remove the PrivateAssets and IncludeAssets), it may work, but who knows what errors that may produce? Worth trying, I'm curious about that scenario too.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I use is to only include TypeScript package in the Debug build. I have to make sure the files are compiled in Debug build first and they go to the Git repository so when anyone builds or publishes with Release version, the files are already there:

```xml
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild" Version="5.2.2"
                          Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
            <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
            <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        </PackageReference>
```